# Testing disk performance: differs with and without using Java

Tags: java, performance, disk, dd

I've been asked to measure current disk performance, as we are planning to replace local disk with network attached storage on our application servers.  Since our applications which write data are written in Java, I thought I would measure the performance directly in Linux, and also using a simple Java test.  However I'm getting significantly different results, particularly for reading data, using what appear to me to be similar tests.  Directly in Linux I'm doing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/cache/test bs=1048576 count=8192
dd if=/data/cache/test of=/dev/null bs=1048576 count=8192
```

My Java test looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestDiskSpeed {
private byte[] oneMB = new byte[1024 * 1024];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new TestDiskSpeed().execute(args);
}

private void execute(String[] args) throws IOException {
    long size = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
    testWriteSpeed(args[0], size);
    testReadSpeed(args[0], size);
}


private void testWriteSpeed(String filePath, long size) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    BufferedOutputStream writer = null;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), 1024 * 1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            writer.write(oneMB);
        }
        writer.flush();
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    String message = "Wrote " + size + "MB in " + elapsed + "ms at a speed of " + calculateSpeed(size, elapsed) + "MB/s";
    System.out.println(message);
}

private void testReadSpeed(String filePath, long size) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    BufferedInputStream reader = null;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 1024 * 1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            reader.read(oneMB);
        }
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    String message = "Read " + size + "MB in " + elapsed + "ms at a speed of " + calculateSpeed(size, elapsed) + "MB/s";
    System.out.println(message);
}

private double calculateSpeed(long size, long elapsed) {
    double seconds = ((double) elapsed) / 1000L;
    double speed = ((double) size) / seconds;
    return speed;
}
```

}

This is being invoked with "java TestDiskSpeed /data/cache/test 8192"

Both of these should be creating 8GB files of zeros, 1MB at a time, measuring the speed, and then reading it back and measuring again.  Yet the speeds I'm consistently getting are:

Linux: write - ~650MB/s

Linux: read - ~4.2GB/s

Java: write - ~500MB/s

Java: read - ~1.9GB/s

Can anyone explain the large discrepancy?

Comment: Basically you're testing disk cache speed on reading. Is that your goal? For that case the overheads of Java can be significant.

Comment: Here is a [good post](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ru/2011/12/java-sequential-io-performance.html) by Martin Thompson on Java I/O performance.

Comment: Buffering only helps if you are making lots of small reads.  I would use NIO for this read/write test in any case.

Comment: @peter I did quite a bit of testing with Martin's code linked to by apangin, I can confirm his observation that NIO code takes long to warm up and then only performs on a par with plain blocking InputStream.

Comment: @apangin There is an important observation burried deep in the comments section there: FileInputStream performs as well as the RandomAccessFile.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, and this is not surprising - both methods are implemented the same way: [FileInputStream](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e52f33586140/src/share/native/java/io/FileInputStream.c#l69), [RandomAccessFile](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e52f33586140/src/share/native/java/io/RandomAccessFile.c#l71), [io_util.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/e52f33586140/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c#l73).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik if I use NIO I get a read speed of 6.8 GB/s.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this using NIO on my system. Ubuntu 15.04 with an i7-3970X

```
public class Main {
    static final int SIZE_GB = Integer.getInteger("sizeGB", 8);
    static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 64 * 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BLOCK_SIZE);
        File tmp = File.createTempFile("delete", "me");
        tmp.deleteOnExit();
        int blocks = (int) (((long) SIZE_GB << 30) / BLOCK_SIZE);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        try (FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(tmp).getChannel()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
                buffer.clear();
                while (buffer.remaining() > 0)
                    fc.write(buffer);
            }
        }
        long mid = System.nanoTime();
        try (FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(tmp).getChannel()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
                buffer.clear();
                while (buffer.remaining() > 0)
                    fc.read(buffer);
            }
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        long size = tmp.length();
        System.out.printf("Write speed %.1f GB/s, read Speed %.1f GB/s%n",
                (double) size/(mid-start), (double) size/(end-mid));

    }
}
```

prints

```
Write speed 3.8 GB/s, read Speed 6.8 GB/s
```

Comment: The key difference between your code and Martin's is that Martin also incorporates the typical idiom to consume the data: `buffer.flip(); while (buffer.hasRemaining()) { checkSum += buffer.get(); }` and analogous code for the `InputStream`. So perhaps the pure I/O transfer to buffer is fast, but it gets drowned out by consumption code. The overarching point would be that I/O is no longer the bottleneck if data is retrieved from the disk cache.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik While true, the comparison in the question is with `dd` writing either lots of zero or copying to /dev/null.  You are right that a non-trivial program will be spending most of it's time doing something useful.

Comment: Absolutely, I don't contest this as the correct answer to the question. I should have in fact replied in the comments under the question. I've run your code and got even more: 7.5 GB/s.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The OP would be lucky to get 500 MB/s in real processing of data esp text.  BTW a SATA drive max'es out at about this point.

Comment: Yes, that's about the right estimate. In my own efforts I'm trying hard to read compressed data at a rate beyond 1 GB/s, I barely achieve it even with 5:1 compression and the fastest native code around (LZ4). The decompression algorithm does almost no processing, it just copies blocks of data according to the instructions encoded in the compressed file.

Comment: I adedd my own testing code because I wanted to stack your NIO against plain old IO. I retrieved virtually identical performance as soon as I added the requirement that the data end up on heap eventually. It is also very interesting to see that using an awkwardly sized read buffer doesn't impact performance at all (the OS handles this with read-ahead anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You may get better performance if you drop the BufferedXxxStream. It's not helping since you're doing 1Mb read/writes, and is cause extra memory copy of the data.

Better yet, you should be using the NIO classes instead of the regular IO classes.

**try-finally**

You should clean up your try-finally code.

```
// Original code
BufferedOutputStream writer = null;
try {
    writer = new ...;
    // use writer
} finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    }
}

// Cleaner code
BufferedOutputStream writer = new ...;
try {
    // use writer
} finally {
    writer.close();
}

// Even cleaner, using try-with-resources (since Java 7)
try (BufferedOutputStream writer = new ...) {
    // use writer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement Peter's great answer, I am adding the code below. It compares head-to-head the performance of the good-old `java.io` with NIO. Unlike Peter, instead of just reading data into a direct buffer, I do a typical thing with it: transfer it into an on-heap byte array. This steals surprisingly little from the performance: where I was getting 7.5 GB/s with Peter's code, here I get 6.0 GB/s.

For the `java.io` approach I can't have a direct buffer, but instead I call the `read` method directly with my target on-heap byte array. Note that this array is smallish and has an awkward size of 555 bytes. Nevertheless I retrieve almost identical performance: 5.6 GB/s. The difference is so small that it would evaporate completely in normal usage, and even in this artificial scenario if I wasn't reading directly from the disk cache.

As a bonus I include at the bottom a method which can be used on Linux and Mac to purge the disk caches. You'll see a dramatic turn in performance if you decide to call it between the write and the read step.

```
public final class MeasureIOPerformance {
        static final int SIZE_GB = Integer.getInteger("sizeGB", 8);
        static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
        static final int blocks = (int) (((long) SIZE_GB << 30) / BLOCK_SIZE);
        static final byte[] acceptBuffer = new byte[555];

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                measure(new ChannelRw());
                measure(new StreamRw());
            }
        }

        private static void measure(RW rw) throws IOException {
            File file = File.createTempFile("delete", "me");
            file.deleteOnExit();
            System.out.println("Writing " + SIZE_GB + " GB " + " with " + rw);
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            rw.write(file);
            long mid = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Reading " + SIZE_GB + " GB " + " with " + rw);
            long checksum = rw.read(file);
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            long size = file.length();
            System.out.printf("Write speed %.1f GB/s, read Speed %.1f GB/s%n",
                    (double) size/(mid-start), (double) size/(end-mid));
            System.out.println(checksum);
            file.delete();
        }

        interface RW {
            void write(File f) throws IOException;
            long read(File f) throws IOException;
        }

        static class ChannelRw implements RW {
            final ByteBuffer directBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BLOCK_SIZE);

            @Override public String toString() {
                return "Channel";
            }

            @Override public void write(File f) throws IOException {
                FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(f).getChannel();
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
                        directBuffer.clear();
                        while (directBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
                            fc.write(directBuffer);
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    fc.close();
                }
            }
            @Override public long read(File f) throws IOException {
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BLOCK_SIZE);
                FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(f).getChannel();
                long checksum = 0;
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
                        buffer.clear();
                        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                            fc.read(buffer);
                        }
                        buffer.flip();
                        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                            buffer.get(acceptBuffer, 0, Math.min(acceptBuffer.length, buffer.remaining()));
                            checksum += acceptBuffer[acceptBuffer[0]];
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    fc.close();
                }
                return checksum;
            }
        }

        static class StreamRw implements RW {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];

            @Override public String toString() {
                return "Stream";
            }

            @Override public void write(File f) throws IOException {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
                        out.write(buffer);
                    }
                } finally {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
            @Override public long read(File f) throws IOException {
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
                long checksum = 0;
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
                        for (int remaining = acceptBuffer.length, read;
                             (read = in.read(buffer)) != -1 && (remaining -= read) > 0; )
                        {
                            in.read(acceptBuffer, acceptBuffer.length - remaining, remaining);
                        }
                        checksum += acceptBuffer[acceptBuffer[0]];
                    }
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
                return checksum;
            }
        }


        public static void purgeCache() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac")) {
                new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "purge")
    //                    .inheritIO()
                        .start().waitFor();
            } else {
                new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "su", "-c", "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches")
    //                    .inheritIO()
                        .start().waitFor();
            }
        }
    }
```